# Calling an instance variable in another class

Tags: python, class, conditional-statements, instance-variables

I am trying to access the instance variable self.code in class Line in class Quote. I am trying to make the following rule pass: when a quote is made containing both a 'door_sign' and 'escape_sign' line they receive 10% off the entire quote.

Here's the code.

```
class Client:
    def __init__(self, postcode):
        self.postcode = postcode


class Line:
    def __init__(self, code, unit_cost, quantity=1):
        self.code = code
        self.unit_cost = unit_cost
        self.quantity = quantity

    def cost(self):

        if self.code == 'door_sign' and self.quantity >=3:
            return self.unit_cost * self.quantity * 0.8
        else:
            return self.unit_cost * self.quantity

class Quote:
    def __init__(self, client=None, lines=[]):
        self.client = client
        self.lines = lines

    def cost(self):
```

**** Here is where my problem lies ****

```
    for l in self.lines:
        if line.code == 'door_sign' and 'escape_sign':
            return sum([l.cost() * 0.9])
        else:
            return sum([l.cost()])

print('Rule')
assert Quote(client=Client(postcode=3000), lines=[
Line(code='escape_sign', unit_cost=20.0, quantity=10),
]).cost() == 200.0
assert Quote(client=Client(postcode=3000), lines=[
Line(code='door_sign', unit_cost=10.0, quantity=1),
Line(code='escape_sign', unit_cost=20.0, quantity=10),
]).cost() == 189.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are always giving a discount since `escape_sign` is always `True` and computing the cost incorrectly by returning early. Why don't you try this in the `def cost` method:

```
def cost(self):
    needed = {'door_sign', 'escape_sign'}
    discount = {l.code for l in self.lines} & needed == needed
    cost = sum(l.cost() for l in self.lines)
    return (cost * 0.9) if discount else cost
```

**Quick edit**, I missed that you want the discount if *both* `escape_sign` and `door_sign` are in the order.

If you want it in one loop:

```
def cost(self):
    door = False
    escape = False
    cost = 0
    for line in self.lines:
        if line.code == 'escape_sign':
            escape = True
        elif line.code == 'door_sign':
            door = True
        cost += line.cost()
    return (cost * 0.9) if (escape and door) else cost
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The loop only returns the cost of the first line of the quote and ignores the second line.

Comment: Nevermind it was my fault, I didn't indent correctly! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Quote:
    def __init__(self, client=None, lines=[]):
        self.client = client
        self.lines = lines
    def cost(self):
        codes={l.code for l in self.lines}
        price_modifier = 0.9 if codes.issuperset({'door_sign','escape_sign'}) else 1.0
        return sum([l.cost()*price_modifier for l in self.lines])
```